# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridspec_kw'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to subplot some data but when I'm running the code the following line give me an error saying the following. Can you someone please tell me what Am I doing wrong ? I have imported. Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gridspec_kw'

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(16, 6), sharex=True, \
                                   gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[2,1]})
```

Comment: Since this piece of code should work fine, we cannot tell you what's wrong unless you provide more information on your system, the way you run it, the versions of the libraries etc. You may simply have a version of matplotlib, which doesn't support it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it was solved after upgrading `matplotlib` to a newer version.

You can check your version with:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)
```

Before upgrade I was in `maplotlib` version `1.3.1`, and after upgrade I was in `2.2.3` version.

And the `gridspec_kw` argument now works fine !

---

Run this `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib` in your terminal to upgrade